# É possível incluir allegro em um Kernel feito em C?

Tags: c, assembly, allegro, kernel

Estudo há algum tempo a construção de Sistemas Operacionais com bootloader em Assembly e kernel em C, e recentemente comecei a estudar allegro. Teoricamente é possível incluir a allegro ao kernel feito em C, mas eu quero saber na pratica... é possível?

Answer (score 1):

Tecnicamente é. Qualquer biblioteca ou aplicativo pode ser implementado ou portado para dentro do kernel.

Mas qual a vantagem? Se a API do Allegro estivesse dentro do kernel e a aplicação que o utiliza do lado de fora, cada chamada ao Allegro envolveria uma syscall e uma troca de contexto, que é "cara" (demora bem mais que uma chamada de função normal).

É possível que o desempenho seja muito melhor com o Allegro fora do kernel, no mesmo espaço de memória que o jogo ou aplicativo. A não ser que você faça o jogo dentro do kernel também, aí na verdade seria uma regressão ao tempo do MS-DOS onde todo o código tem acesso direto ao hardware o tempo todo.

E como você deve saber, qualquer bug no código que está do lado de dentro do kernel faz o computador travar. Certamente o Allegro tem bugs...

No kernel só deveria estar código que precisa ter acesso total ao hardware, e precisa ter acesso controlado, seja por usuário ou por conjunto de permissões.

Também acaba ficando muito código no kernel que, por razões pragmáticas, funciona mais rápido se estiver lá. É o caso da maioria dos drivers de dispositivo, sistemas de arquivos, etc. Mesmo assim existem muitos drivers que funcionam em user mode, e há casos inclusive onde user-mode é mais rápido (por exemplo se um único aplicativo faz uso de uma placa de rede, o conjunto fica mais rápido se o próprio aplicativo conter o driver dessa placa).

Comment: Entendo. O que você recomenda para implementar imagens no kernel? No caso eu penso que é o primeiro passo para o desenvolvimento GUI

Comment: Na verdade teria de escolher em primeiro lugar a arquitetura do driver de video. Num projeto que participei ("teu passado te condena!") utilizava framebuffer do Linux, cujo driver está inteiramente dentro do kernel, então seria uma opção, fazer o driver de framebuffer do Alegro conversar diretamente com o driver do kernel sem syscall.